# Boostrap Carousel with Slides of different widths?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Has anyone come across a solution, using Bootstrap's native carousel, like this? http://sastairs.com.au/project/glen-huntly-road/

The slides (items) at different widths? Adjacent slides are visible?

I can usually find answers, but this one has stumped me. Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do this? As a user, I find it really annoying if slides are different heights/widths as it puts the arrows in different positions, meaning I can't just set the mouse and then focus on the content - after each slide I have to take my focus off the content to find the arrow for the next slide.

Comment: Hi Amy, yes there are design reasons for this. The arrows won't be jumping around.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

It has responsive options, and good bootstrap integration

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

```
  autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

  items : 4,
  itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
  itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
```

});

});

Comment: Thanks Mimoir. Owl slider looks good. I'll see if it might work.

Comment: I am going to close this thread, but will say that owl carousel is pretty nice, but is really buggy. I've probably put about 30 hours into i and it still doesn't work the way I'd like. Bootstrap carousel would have been up and running in an hour. I can't recommend this item to others.